# Find next point in ellipse given the chord length

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, conic-sections

I would like to draw a cloud programmatically. For this reason I need to know where to draw the next circle around the ellipse.

Given the chord (circle radius), how can I calculate the next point in the ellipse?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean that the cloud resembles an ellipse?

Comment: yep, thinking of basing it on an ellipse. Like [this one](http://www.clker.com/clipart-thought-cloud.html), for instance.

Comment: Given the ellipse formula, say $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$, and the circle radius $r$, and a starting point $(x_1,y_1)$ on the ellipse, perhaps you mean that the "next point" should be on the intersection of the ellipse with the circle radius $r$ centered at $(x_1,y_1)$. If you solve this and get $(x_2,y_2)$ for the next center, etc., it will likely turn out that going once around the ellipse you don't end up back at the first circle. That would make the cloud look uneven-- is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the ellipse is centered at $(0,0)$ with equation $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2$, with major and minor axes alligned with the $x$ and $y$ axes. This ellipse can be parametrized by $(x,y)=(a \cos t, b \sin t)$, and as the parameter $t$ increases, the point moves around the ellipse in a counterclockwise direction.

If your first center is at $(x_1,y_1)$ then first find the $t$ value (call this $t_1$) by use of $\cos t_1=x_1/a,\ \sin t_1 = y_1/b.$ Now let $t$ be the parameter value for your "next" circle center, which is to be the first point, going around the ellipse counterclockwise, which is at distance $r$ from $(x_1,y_1).$ Set up the squared distance to $(x_1,y_1)$ as
$$f(t)=a^2(\cos t - \cos t_1)^2 +b^2 (\sin t -\sin t_1)^2.$$
This starts out as $0$ when $t=t_1$, and you can (since it's a program) now increment $t$ and get the least $t$ beyond $t_1$ for which $f(t)=r^2.$ [This will likely involve some sort of bisection approach, once you find a value of $t$ for which $f(t)>r^2$, then back up, etc. (I tried getting an exact expression for this first $t$ value but it was a bit involved, maybe not possible in closed form...)

Anyway after the value of $t$ is found as above your "next center" say $(x_2,y_2)$ becomes $(a \cos t,b \sin t).$

Comment: Thanks @coffeemath! My understanding is that I should first find the angle from the center of the ellipse to the point of the chord (_t_), then simply using the ellipse formula to get the location (which is pretty easy). Still not sure how to implement this formula to get the next _t_ though. t1 = ?

Comment: Note that the parameter $t$ in the above is not the angle from the center of the ellipse. If you use equally spaced parameter $t$ values, the resulting centers for the circles will not be equally spaced at any fixed distance $r$. Even if one re-writes the ellipse in polar coordinates, so that say $\theta$ actually is the angle at the center formed by the $x$ axis and a given ellipse point, then evan if equally spaced $\theta$ are chosen, one still doesn't get equally spaced points on the ellipse for the centers of the circles.

Comment: Sorry if I am being thick, so you are saying I can't do what I want? Wouldn't I just need a formula to get the intersection of 2 ellipses, one being a circle centered on the perimeter of the big ellipse?

Comment: Found the code for interception of 2 ellipses [here](http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/Intersection.js), will give it a go tomorrow. The demo should be [this one](http://www.kevlindev.com/geometry/2D/intersections/intersect_ellipse_ellipse.svg)

Comment: You're not being "thick", that idea of solving the two equations for the intersection of the circle centered at a point of the ellipse of radius $r$ with the given ellipse is exactly what I was doing with a numerical approach. Actually I miswrote that the exact answer might be unfindable, it's only two second degree equations after all.